# Как увеличить память IDE Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

В последнее время я разработал несколько проектов и заметил, что IDE Android Studio слишком долго загружает и запускает.

То, интересно, как увеличить память IDE Android Studio?

Чтобы ускорить запуск IDE и, следовательно, ускорить разработку...

Comment: рекомендаций много, гуглите Android Studio speed

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы ускорить IDE, купите SSD диск. На моем ноутбуке с 10 гб ОЗУ, разница в скорости загрузки между SSD и HDD - раз 5. Не ОЗУ грузит IDEA, а именно накопитель (хотя без ОЗУ нормально ничего работать не будет).

ОЗУ конфигурируется в файле `idea.vmoptions`, в каталоге `bin`, который в каталоге с Вашей IDE (IDEA или Android Studio). Параметр `xmx`.

Так же для ускорения компиляции можно использовать параллельную компиляцию (на эту тему в интернете довольно много статьей).